# How to load remote SVG image using Coil in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, svg, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I'm failing to load [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg) in `Image` using Coil in Jetpack Compose

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Coil doesn't support SVG by default.

According to [documentation](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/svgs/), you need to:

1. Add following dependency:

   ```
   implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:$coil_version")
   ```
2. Set `SvgDecoder` as decoder:

   Coil **2.0.0** version:

   ```
   AsyncImage(
       model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
           .data(svgImageUrl)
           .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
           .build(),
       contentDescription = null
   )
   ```

   Coil **1.4.0** version:

   ```
   Image(
       rememberImagePainter(
           data = svgImageUrl,
           builder = {
               decoder(SvgDecoder(LocalContext.current))
           }
       ),
       contentDescription = null
   )
   ```

p.s. note that if you set the decoder this way, Coil will not be able to work with non-SVG images in this painter, so if you want some general solution, you should check the url extension and add the decoder accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for adding a new decoder has changed a bit from 1.4.0 to 2.x.x.

```
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
.components {
    add(SvgDecoder.Factory())
}
.build()
```

You can find the latest syntax here: https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/svgs/

Answer (score 5):

I was working on `Jetpack Compose` app and the urls I received from a remote API contained both `.png/jpeg` and `.svg` file extensions.

I added dependencies for both Coil Compose and SVG flavors for `Coil Version 2.0.0` which is the latest version as of January 2023.

```
// Coil
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.2.2")
```

I then chained `decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())` to Image.Request builder.

```
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(context = context)
                    .data(urlPng or urlSvg)
                    .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
                    .error(R.drawable.empty_flag)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.empty_logo)
                    .build()
            )

            Image(painter = painter ....)
```

The updated `.components { add(SvgDecoder.Factory())}` call mentioned by ***[@jendress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71753819/7839518)*** was not resolved in my case and so I went with `decoderFactory()`.

Both urls with `.png/.jpeg` and `.svg` worked well and rendered the correct image without errors.